# Sending multiple cookies in one HTTP header

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am confused about how cookies work in general.

Suppose i have

- Cookie A for www.mysite.com (let's call it Path A)
- Cookie  B for www.mysite.com/dir1 (Path B)
- Cookie C for www.mysite.com/dir1/dir2       (Path C)

Now if I visit  root path, only Cookie A is sent to server and used?
If i request files in Path B, Cookie A and B are both sent to server, but only B is used?
If i tey to access files in Path C, all 3 cookies are sent, only C is used?

If it indeed works that way, what happens to the unused cookies?

Could the situation where multiple cookies with the same **name** exist for ONE particular webpage exist?
Thanks

Comment: Please read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie - cookies work with a _path_ - if it is "/" then all pages on the whole website can read the cookie

Comment: So you mean if i have a cookie for an entire website, i wont be able to have a cookie for a particular page?

Comment: Hi, i did mean path, but used webpages in my original post. I have edited it. I do u derstand your first comment, and checked the google link. However, setting cookies only for the entire website seems to be just a recommendation. "Path" option is the option for sepcifying what path the cookie belongs to. And this is where i got confused. What if i have separate cookies for parent and children paths? How would this be handled by the browser and the webserver?  Thanks

Comment: A path of /dir1 would only share its cookies with pages in dir1, not with root and not with /dir2